# How to access all data in a nested array that has no variables?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

Getting data from a nested array is usually quite easy.
If my array looks like this:

```
    myArray: [
      {
        myNestedArray: [
          {
            name: 'Some name'
          },
          {
            name: 'Some other name'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I can just access the nested value by doing the following:

```
<div v-for="name in myArray">
  {{ name.myNestedArray[0].name }}
</div>
```

But what if I have a nested array that does not define any variables?

example:

```
    myArray: [
      {
        myNestedArray: [
          'Rob',
          'John',
          'Jacob'
        ]
      }
    ]
```

If I do this:

```
name.myNestedArray[0]
```

it will only return the first name in the array: Rob.

If I do this:

```
name.myNestedArray
```

it will output all the names in square brackets, and if there is an item where the nested array is empty, it will output empty square brakcets.

Example of such output:

```
[]
[ "Rob", "John", "Jacob" ]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[ "Tom" ]
[ "Liz" ]
[ "Martin, James" ]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

What I would like is for the output to be like this:

```
Rob 
John
Jacob
Tom
Liz
Martin
James
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to just understand the difference, We always access array elements by using `index` and Object property values by the `key`.

As per the requirement, You can print the nested array elements in the template by using two ways.

1. By join the array elements with line break `<br>` and then use it in `v-html` attribute. But while using this make sure that you don't have any malicious or sensitive data as it could be exposed to XSS security breach.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myArray: [
      {
        myNestedArray: [
          'Rob',
          'John',
          'Jacob'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(name, index) in myArray" :key="index">
    <p v-html="name.myNestedArray.join('<br>')"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. By iterating a loop two times using `v-for` attribute.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myArray: [
      {
        myNestedArray: [
          'Rob',
          'John',
          'Jacob'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(name, index) in myArray" :key="index">
    <p v-for="(item, id) in name.myNestedArray" :key="id">
      {{ item }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
<div v-for="name in myArray">
 <div v-for="(i,index) in name.myNestedArray.length()" :key="index">
   {{name.myNestedArray[index]}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need for accessing from the index. Just doing `v-for="val in name.myNestedArray"` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

1. Outer loop on `myArray`.
2. Inner loop on `myNestedArray`

Here is a working demo-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      myArray: [
      {
        myNestedArray: [
          'Rob',
          'John',
          'Jacob'
        ]
      },
      {
        myNestedArray: []
      },
      {
        myNestedArray: [
          'Tom',
          'Liz',
          'Martin'
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="name in myArray">
    <div v-for="nestedData in name.myNestedArray">
      {{ nestedData }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create computed property and fatten arrays for one loop:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      myArray: [
      {myNestedArray: [
          'Rob',
          'John',
          'Jacob'
        ]},
      {myNestedArray: []},
      {myNestedArray: [
          'Tom',
          'Liz',
          'Martin'
        ]}
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    flatArray() {
      return this.myArray.map(m => m.myNestedArray).flat()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="nestedData in flatArray">
    {{ nestedData }}
  </div>
</div>
```